# DateTime (Timezones) in PHP Web Applications

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I learnt that I should Store UTC and Show in local time. How can I query the SQL database for rows that are due today, according to user time. I have a Todo table with a column `dueOn` it contains the UTC Unix Timestamp in `int`.

I think it will look something like

```
SELECT * FROM Todos 
WHERE dueOn BETWEEN {today's timestamp} AND {tomorrow's timestamp}
```

What will I use to get today's & tomorrow's timestamp? I think this sounds simple, but I am very confused with all the similar methods for date & time

**UPDATE**

I am wondering of something like below is correct

```
// set default timezone to the user's timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore"); 
// get UTC datetime for today & tomorrow
$today = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('UTC')); 
$tomorrow =  clone($today);
$tomorrow->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Todos WHERE dueOn BETWEEN ' . $today->getTimestamp() . ' AND ' . $tomorrow->getTimestamp();
echo $sql;
```

Can I somehow get the user's time without using `date_default_timezone_set`? Or will it be allright as that will just set the timezone for the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your SQL query, use CONVERT_TZ to convert the due date from the user's time to UTC.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM Todos
WHERE CONVERT_TZ('2011-01-21', 'EST', 'UTC') BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: suppose I want to grab the current timestamp according to the user's timezone, how will I do it, instead of a hardcoded value? In PHP & MySQL if possible, I will be using Doctrine, so I won't be using MySQL directly, but I will like to learn too

Comment: In SQL, if the user's timezone is EST, `CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'EST', 'UTC')`. In PHP, `date_default_timezone_set('EST')` then use `date()` or any other datetime function.